How to generate an overall Rust code coverage report with some crates excluded?
My rust project consists of several crates; let's imagine they are Dep1, Dep2, Dep3, Root1, Root2. Dep2 depends on Dep1, Root1 depends on Dep2 and Dep3, Root2 - on Dep1 and Dep3.
My goal is to generate an overall coverage report using gcov for Root2 and Root1 ONLY.
So I'm looking for an ability to EITHER merge several reports (each one for each separate Root* crate) into a single one OR generate an overall report for all the Root* crates in one command.
Besides that, I might need to be able to exclude some dependencies from that overall build. For instance, I don't want the report to include coverage of Dep1 at all.
Is this possible?
The requirement is to use grcov and no other alternatives. To generate a single report for Root1 I use the following command:
grcov . --binary-path ./Root1/target/ -s . -t html,lcov,cobertura --branch -o Root1/coverage

It works, but there are 2 things in it I'm not satisfied with:

The output report does not include report for Root2 (but I need the overall one, both for Root1 and Root2).
The output report includes Dep1 in it, though I don't want it here.

